# Как рендерить результаты отработки mongodb в ejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, ejs

У меня есть nodeapi c mongoDb. Не могу вывести содержимое базы данных в шаблон, вместо результата выводит литерал функции. Если прописать рендер в контроллере - всё работает, но ощущение, что так делать не стоит.

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser"); 
var articlesController = require("./controllers/artcls");

var db = require("./db");

var app = express();
var all = articlesController.all;

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

db.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/myblog", function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }
    app.listen(3000, function() {
        console.log("I am working only for you, my Lord")
    });
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    var all =  articlesController.all;
    res.render("index.ejs", { all: all });

});
```

контроллер

```
var Article = require("../models/articles");

exports.all = function(req, res) {
    Article.all(function(err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        console.log(docs)
        return res.send(docs);

    })
};
```

Модель

```
var db = require("../db");
var ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;

exports.all = function(call) {
    db.get().collection("articles").find().toArray(function(err, docs) {
        call(err, docs);
    })
};
```

Comment: Проблема в колбэке с req, res она есть и в сервере и в контроллере, но не знаю какую убрать и как.

Comment: а поч функция ничего не возвращает?